# Create arrays of arrays and use dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists:

```
x = ['1','5','X','9']
y = ['X','9','9P']
```

which I have combined like this:

```
z = [x,y]
print(z)
```

So, "z" is a list of two lists and it looks like this:

```
[['1', '5', 'X', '9'], ['X', '9', '9P']]
```

I have this dictionary:

```
delqType = {
    '1'  : 0,
    '2'  : 3,
    '3'  : 4,
    '4'  : 5,
    '5'  : 6,
    '7'  : 19,
    '8'  : 21,
    '8A' : 20,
    '8P' : 16,
    '9'  : 22,
    '9B' : 18,
    '9P' : 15,
    'UR' : 23,
    'X'  : -99999
    }
```

I want to apply the dictionary delqType to the list "z" in order to get this new list (called "t") that looks like:

```
[[0, 6, -99999, 22], [-99999, 22, 15]]
```

I have tried this code:

```
t = []
for i in range(len(z)):
    for j in range(len(z[i])):
        
        t.append(delqType[z[i][j]])
    next
```

But I get one list (and not a list of two lists as I want):

```
[0, 6, -99999, 22, -99999, 22, 15]
```

How can I get a list of two lists containing the elements after they have been transformed using the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested list comprehension.

```
t = [[delqType[i] for i in list_i] for list_i in z]
print(t)
[[0, 6, -99999, 22], [-99999, 22, 15]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should created the nested lists in `t`, one for each nested list of `z`. In addition it will be simpler to iterate the items instead of the indices:

```
t = []
for sub in z:
    t.append([])
    for item in sub:
        t[-1].append(delqType[item])
```

Another nice way is to use the [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) operator to map the list of keys to the list of values:

```
from operator import itemgetter
t = [itemgetter(*sub)(delqType) for sub in z]
```

Comment: Using `itemgetter` with multiple keys is a nice idea, but may be a little too high-level considering the question, and will also [return a tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter); not sure it matches OP's expectation ;-)

Comment: @Joël - you are right :) but as the question is about mapping lists of keys to lists of values it is nice to show the option (and have it for future readers)

Answer (score 1):

As you want to get a 2 dimensions list, you need to append a *list* inside your *first* `for` loop.

(But also, please use the `for` loop to directly extract values, instead of using indices !)

So, this would look like:

```py
t = []
for sublist in z:
    new_sublist = []
    for key in sublist:
        newlist.append(...)
    t.append(new_sublist)
```

I let to you to fill the internals of the deepest `for` loop, as an exercise, to ensure you got it correctly :-)

Side note: your code sample is not correct, as there is no `next` keyword in Python!! Please be sure to provide the exact code you executed.